# Service Fabric CreateService Permissions

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have a service running as a domain user, and it's unable to call FabricRuntime.CreateService to create a service within it's own application. However, this isn't an Azure cluster. It's a local cluster. Where I'm using a specific domain account.

I am doing this as well on an Azure cluster (no domain accounts), using the "default user" (whatever a SF app runs with when you don't specify anything), and it's working fine.

So, I'm pretty sure that the account isn't getting some needed permission. But I'm not sure what.

I want to limit it as strictly as possible to what it needs to be able to do.

Answer (score 0):

That user that you're running as probably is not an "administrator" (doesn't have access to the cluster administration certificate, or you don't have this set up). You can find out information about the different security roles built into the cluster [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-security-roles). You typically would need to have an additional certificate added to the admin set, and then use that certificate in your service when you want to take administrative actions in the cluster. You set these additional identities in the cluster config.